# Use Django's RedirectView with a named url

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to make my `a_detail` redirect to my `a_detail_slug` url. I want to use the named url for this but I haven't succeeded yet, this is what I've tried:

```
url(r'^a/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<filler>[\w-]+)/$', AList.as_view(template_name="a.html"), name="a_detail_slug"),

url(r'^a/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy("a_detail_slug"),), name="a_detail"),
```

This is meant to catch any link with a valid pk and redirect to that page with an appended filler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`a_detail_slug` requires 2 params (`pk` and `filler`) but you pass none of them. The easiest way will be extend RedirectView:

```
class ARedirect(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, pk):
        filler = get_filler_somehow()
        return reverse('a_detail_slug', args=(pk, filler))
```